# Android Java Webview: The webview screenshot function works on all content, but when it comes to videos, it will take a blank screenshot

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-webview, screenshot

In my Android Java app, I'm trying to take a screenshot on WebView and send the image to the API for proof functionality. The current function works with all contents loaded to webview, but when it comes to video, it takes a blank screenshot or just takes the background without the video.

Can someone help me figure out how to take screenshots of videos in WebView as well?

Currently, I'm using the below code to take screenshots.

```
public void takeScreenshot() {
        String fileName = generateScreenshotFilename();
        try {
            // wait for the view to be fully drawn
            Thread.sleep(500);

            // create bitmap screen capture
            View v1 = this.activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                    v1.getWidth(), v1.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
            );
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            v1.draw(canvas);

            // Start of API call
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            MultipartBody.Builder requestBodyBuilder = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                    .setType(MultipartBody.FORM);
            String macAddress = Constants.getMacAddress(this.activity);

            if (bitmap != null) {
                ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
                byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

                requestBodyBuilder.addFormDataPart("image", fileName,
                        RequestBody.create(byteArray, MEDIA_TYPE_PNG));
            }

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(Constants.API_URL + "/capture/upload/snap/" + macAddress)
                    .post(requestBodyBuilder.build())
                    .build();

            if (duplicatedScreenshotCall) {
                return;
            }

            duplicatedScreenshotCall = true;
            SendScreenshotAPI sendScreenshotAPI = new SendScreenshotAPI(client, request);
            sendScreenshotAPI.execute();

            // Check if the looper is already prepared for this thread
            if (Looper.myLooper() == null) {
                // Prepare the looper for the background thread
                Looper.prepare();
            }
            new Handler().postDelayed(() -> duplicatedScreenshotCall = false, Constants.DOUBLE_PRESS_INTERVAL);
            // Start the message loop for the background thread if it wasn't prepared before
            if (Looper.myLooper() == null) {
                Looper.loop();
            }
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I have used the below code as well, and it also results in the above code. The above code is more reliable because of the Android API 28 `view.getDrawingCache()` has been deprecated.

```
View v1 = this.activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

DRM content viewers may invalidate the cache beforehand capturing the screen. This is done in order to prevent capturing DRM protected material from the lowest level. Some software is more intelligent about it, but most are denying access to the view right-out.

Comment: However, the presented website contents were created by myself. I didn't use any DRM protection methods.

Comment: This is what I said: Some software is more intelligent about it, but most are denying access to the view right-out.